# Deixar o tooltip visivel sem ser no hover

Tags: css, css3, css-hover

Quero que o `tooltip` fique aparecendo assim que carrega a pagina, sem ser pelo efeito de `hover`.

```css
[class*="tooltip"]{
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
}
[class*="tooltip"]:after,[class*="tooltip"]:before{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    opacity:0;
}
[class*="tooltip"]:after{
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    content:attr(aria-label);
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    padding:0 10px;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    background:#222;
    border-radius:4px;
    text-shadow:0 0 5px #000;
    white-space:nowrap
}
[class*="tooltip"]:before{
    content:'';
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-width:6px;
    border-style:solid
}
[class*="tooltip"]:hover:after,[class*="tooltip"]:focus:after,[class*="tooltip"]:hover:before,[class*="tooltip"]:focus:before{
    opacity:1
}
/* tooltip-top */
.tooltip-top:after,.tooltip-top:before{

    transition:bottom .25s ease-in-out;
    bottom:90%;
    left:-9999px;
    margin-bottom:12px
}
.tooltip-top:before{
    border-color:#222 transparent transparent transparent;
    margin-bottom:0
}
.tooltip-top:hover:after,.tooltip-top:focus:after,.tooltip-top:hover:before,.tooltip-top:focus:before{
    bottom:85%;
    left:0;

}
.tooltip-top:hover:before,.tooltip-top:focus:before{
    left:15px
}
```

```html
<a href="#component-tooltip" role="tooltip" class="tooltip-top btn" aria-label="Explore inadimplência por empreeendimentos">Top</a>
```

Comment: O efeito de hover se dá pelo seletor `:hover`. Tente removê-lo ou substiuí-lo no seu código.

Comment: deu certo! Acho que agora consigo setar na class tooltip-top depois de uns 5 segundos ela desaparecer usando setTimeout,certo? http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/303453/

Comment: Tatah não precisa disso, faz um @keyframes e uma animação de fadeOut com delay de 5s na animação... Se quiser posso postar essa opção como resposta

Comment: @hugocsl eu aceito a opção, para me ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para deixar a seta do tooltipe aparecendo o tempo inteiro vc pode a grosso modo remover a *pseudo-classe* `:hover` das classes que o tenham como o Anderson falou, ou vc pode refinar o CSS colocando os estilos que estavam na *pseudo-classe* `:hover` direto na classe original do elemento.

Para fazer a seta desaparece depois de um determinado tempo basta vc fazer um @keyframes no css, e colocar nessa animação um `delay` de `3s` ou `5s` como queira `animation-delay: 3s;`. Deixei os comentários no código.

Veja o exemplo, a seta some depois de `3s`

```css
[class*="tooltip"]{
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none;
}
[class*="tooltip"]:after,[class*="tooltip"]:before{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
  opacity:1;
  transition:bottom .25s ease-in-out;
  bottom:90%;
  left:-9999px;
  margin-bottom:12px;
  /* coloca a animação no elemento */
  animation: fadeOut 200ms linear forwards;
  /* tempo que demora pra animação começar */
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
[class*="tooltip"]:after{
  content:attr(aria-label);
  box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  height:25px;
  line-height:25px;
  padding:0 10px;
  font-size:1.2rem;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  background:#222;
  border-radius:4px;
  text-shadow:0 0 5px #000;
  white-space:nowrap
}
[class*="tooltip"]:before{
  content:'';
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-width:6px;
  border-style:solid;
  left:15px;
  border-color:#222 transparent transparent transparent;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#component-tooltip" role="tooltip" class="tooltip-top btn" aria-label="Explore inadimplência por empreeendimentos">Top</a>
```

Comment: muito obrigada :)

Comment: @tatah acabei de editar o código nesse segundo :D, aproveitei para retirar as classes redundantes já que vc não precisa do :hover, se vc quiser o código antigo, basta entrar no histórico de Edição e pegar o outro código que só removi o :hover ok, é só clicar no link "editada" ai encima. Boa sorte ai, qq dúvida é só dar o toque.